# Copying all KEYS from one db to another in same Redis

Tags: redis

I am trying to copy all keys from db=2 to db=3 in same redis which is running at port 6380.

I have followed  few other SO questions but getting NOKEY as response. Please find query for the same.Could anybody help what is wrong with below command?

```
redis-3.2.8/src/redis-cli  -p 6380 -n 2 --scan | xargs redis- 
3.2.8/src/redis-cli -p 6380 migrate localhost 6380 '' 3 0 copy keys
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error.

In your case, the keys you scanned might have been expired when you try to migrate it. If the key you want to migrate doesn't exist in the source database, `MIGRATE` command will return *NOKEY*.